# Are global gateway splash screens still a UX best practice?

Tags: usability, website-design, navigation

I was reading about Global Gateway ui/ux design and I've found out that there are two kinds: the "Global Gateway Splash Screen" and the "Permanent Global Gateway".  A Global Gateway is basically a UI that allows the user to chose his country and language when he visits a website. For example, let's say you want to purchase some sneakers from puma, but you're in Brazil. You will be given the option to chose Brazil as the country and Portuguese as a language. Here's an example:

Here you can see that chosen country is Chile, and the website is in spanish.  This example is known as a "Permanent Global Gateway", meaning that it is always there, visible to the user.
[image]

The "Global Gateway Splash Screen" as it name suggests, is a splash screen that the website displays for the user to chose country and language right there, before actually entering the website. Here's an example from an old Ikea site:

[image]

I know that the permanent one is commonly used today but I haven't found much information on the splash one.
Is it still a UX best practice?

Comment: Hi Paula, welcome to SEUX. Providing example images might give a better idea of what you're talking about and the difference between those screens as not everyone might be familiar with the terminology you use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure thing! I will add images :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To the extent possible reduce the decisions a user has to make before they can experience your website.

1. Use their IP address to predict geo-location. Default your website to that country.
2. Have affordances which allow users to change language / country easily. (A flag is easier to recognize than script which I can't understand.)

Comment: As far as I know, browsers already send language preferences as HTTP headers. These should be preferred over IP data, which could be misleading. Imagine working abroad for a prolonged period of time, for instance.